# Como abrir Makefile no windows?

Tags: windows, makefile

Gostaria de saber como abrir o makefile no windows. Me mandaram um arquivo que contem o makefile, porem não consigo abrir. Instalei o Cygwin para tentar "rodar" o Makefile porem não adiantou (abri o programa e arrastei o Makefile), ele diz que certos comandos não foram encontrados. Obrigado.

O que está escrito no make:

```html
#
#  Makefile
#
#############################################################
#
#
CC = gcc
CPP = g++
#
# Use only one of the next two flags
#OPTIMIZE = -O3
DEBUG = -g
#
#CFLAGS = -Wall $(OPTIMIZE)  $(DEBUG)
CFLAGS = $(OPTIMIZE)  $(DEBUG)
#
#
#
LIBS = -lm
#
ALLDEFS = 
#
OBJECTS = lsystem.o vartree.o gstack.o psinterface.o
#
EXECUTABLE = lsystem
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
#
.c.o: ; $(CC) -c $(ALLDEFS) $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $*.c
.cpp.o: ; $(CPP) -c $(ALLDEFS) $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $*.cpp
#
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
 $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
#
lsystem.o: lsystem.h psinterface.h
vartree.o: vartree.h lsystem.h
gstack.o: gstack.h lsystem.h
psinterface.o: psinterface.h
#
clean :
 rm -f *.o *.ln $(EXECUTABLE) *.exe *~ *.bak
strip:
 strip $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: entrar em linha de comando nessa pasta e executar: `make`

Answer (score 1):

Se você tiver Visual Studio, execute o prompt de comando Visual Studio a partir do menu Iniciar (geralmente dentro da pasta Visual Studio Tools, vá para o diretório que contém Makefile.win e digite o seguinte:

nmake -f Makefile.win
Você também pode usar o prompt de comando normal e executar vsvars32.bat (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools para VS2012). Isso irá configurar o ambiente para executar nmake e encontrar as ferramentas do compilador.